# Firebase sometimes not calling database

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to set a listener single value event and it works usually. (Doing this with a pull to refresh - it works, even if I kill the app and reopen, or have the android system reclaim the memory in the background).

However after probably a certain period of time (couple hours), I go back to the app and try to access it and the code below doesn't fire anymore. And it stays in this inoperable state (however I verify that everything is there). It lasts until I basically log out and log back in.

I put a log in the onDataChange method and it doesn't fire. I put it outside of it and it fires.

Here is my code:

```
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(context.getString(R.string.firebase_jobs))
                .child(userId).
                addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                        new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot jobSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    JobItem jobItem = jobSnapShot.getValue(JobItem.class);
                                    // Add the ID into the jobItem
                                    jobItem.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                                    // Set the jobItem
                                    arrayList.add(jobItem);
                                    subscriber.onNext(jobItem);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
    }
```

Has anybody experienced the code of where it sometimes is not able to call in the code? Thanks!

Edit: I try to log out while its firing and I receive the log error message:

```
E/FirebaseRetrieveData: onCancelled: Permission denied
```

So the thing is firing, it is just taking a long time to get the data back... if it ever does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the intended behavior of [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html). As described from docs:

> It is triggered one time and then will not be triggered again.

Unless you're aiming for something different? Did I misunderstand something in your post? Were you aiming for you are only to listen to a specific single value? If yes, I think you should've used `addValueEventListener()` instead.

**EDIT:**

Just in case others see this. Here is the latest docs link for [addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#public-methods).

Comment: Mhmm... sorry -- I meant it triggers once, is okay. I do a pull to refresh and it triggers fine. Kill the app, leave it to run in the background and having the system reclaim the memory (killing it), and restarting it still works. HOWEVER I leave my phone and come back a couple of hours later, and it doesn't seem to be able to trigger anymore, and become stucks in a non-triggerable state. That is the problem.

Comment: Yep. That is the intended behavior for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`. It only triggers one time, then doesn't anymore. If you want to listen for every event on a specific reference/child, you should use `addValueEventListener()` instead.

Comment: Ah okay... makes sense. Firebase docs seem to be misleading at times (to me anyway). Thanks, will try!

Comment: No worries. I made an edit. The first link I included was the legacy docs. I added the one for the newer documents. Cheers! :)